# How to edit .bst file to use texttt typewriter font?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, koma-script, typewriter

I'm using the `scrreprt` document class and BibTeX, Version 0.99d with `apsrev4-2` for by bibliography. I'd like to modify my local `.bst` file such that the eprint field is printed with the `\texttt` typewriter font. I assume that I have to modify the `FUNCTION {format.eprint}` function, but I have no idea how.

For reference, this is how the relevant part in my .bst file looks like:

```
FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{
  eprint duplicate$ empty$
  control.eprint #0 <
  or
    { pop$ "" }
    {
      duplicate$
      ""
        archive duplicate$ empty$ { pop$ archiv.base } 'skip$ if$ *
        "/" *
        swap$ *
        "{" swap$ * "}" *
      swap$
      ""
        archivePrefix duplicate$ empty$ { pop$ "" } { ":" * } if$ *
        swap$ *
        primaryClass  duplicate$ empty$ { pop$ "" } { " [" swap$ * "]" * } if$ *
        "{" swap$ * "}" *
      *
      eprint.command swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{
  eprint duplicate$ empty$
  control.eprint #0 <
  or
    { pop$ "" }
    {
      duplicate$
      ""
        archive duplicate$ empty$ { pop$ archiv.base } 'skip$ if$ *
        "/" *
        swap$ *
        "{" swap$ * "}" *
      swap$
      "\ttfamily " %%% INSERT HERE 
        archivePrefix duplicate$ empty$ { pop$ "" } { ":" * } if$ *
        swap$ *
        primaryClass  duplicate$ empty$ { pop$ "" } { " [" swap$ * "]" * } if$ *
        "{" swap$ * "}" *
      *
      eprint.command swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
```

Note that for `scrreprt` and other KOMA classes, one must use `\ttfamily` instead of `\tt`.